# How to increase/decrease space in thumbnail images on Product Page (catalog-product-view) Magento

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.6

I am trying to increase/decrease spacing of thumbnail images on (Product Detail Page) but didn't get any proper solution. Please let me know if there is any option available in magento 2.[image]

Comment: I believe you have made some changes in the code. You can have a look at the html as it seems to be minor css change. By default if you check magento sample data it is having no space.

Comment: Cannot be done by CSS because this section contains internal/inline CSS which is coming either from gallery.phtml file or from JS.

Comment: Why dont you try to enable template path hints to see what file it is coming from?

Comment: I already know the file but don't know from there this space can increase or decrease...

Answer (score 5):

Well I set in the the app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/etc/view.xml and easy you can set **thumbmargin** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
        <var name="gallery">
            <var name="thumbmargin">20</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="navdir">vertical</var>
            <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
            <var name="navarrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->            
            <var name="loop">false</var>
            <var name="fullscreen">
                <var name="navdir">vertical</var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </vars>
</view>
```

Comment: This is the best and easiest approach. Overriding the gallery template works fine, but it's too much effort if the only changes needed are parameters available in the view.xml file.

Comment: Thanks this was a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that magento 2 does not have an xml option/configuration for this, but Fotorama yes.

Check the following link https://fotorama.io/docs/4/options/

**thumbmargin**

*Size of thumbnail margins.*

I've fixed this adding one more option in gallery override of my theme. (gallery.phtml)

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": 
                  <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                  "thumbmargin":30,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                "breakpoints": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it's working fine